# Call a function after saving a model

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-signals

I'm working on a Django application connected to a LDAP server. Here's the trick i'm trying to do.

I have a model called *system* containing some information about computers. When i add a new *system*, the model generates a unique UUID, like and AutoField. **The point is that this parameter is generated when saving**, and only the first time.
After saved, i need a function to keep that UUID and create a new object on my LDAP.
Since i didn't know a lot about signals, i tried overriding the model save function in this way:

```
def save(self):

        # import needed modules
        import ldap
        import ldap.modlist as modlist

        [--OPERATIONS ON THE LDAP--]

        super(System, self).save()
```

In this way, if i modify an existing *system* all work as should, because its UUID has been generated already. But if i try adding a new *system* i find the error UUID is None, and i can't work with an empty variable on LDAP (also it would be useless, don't u think so?)

It seems i need to call the function that work on LDAP **after the *system* is saved**, and so after an UUID has been generated. I tried to unserstand how to create a post_save function but i couldn't get it.
How can i do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you stated on your own, you do need signals, it will allow your code to stay more clean and seperate logic between parts.

The usual approach is to place signals just at the end of your models file:

```
# Signals
from django.dispatch import receiver

@receiver(models.signals.post_save, sender=YourModel)
def do_something(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):

    ....
```

On the above example we connect the post_save signal with the do_something function, this is performed through the decorator **@receiver**, sender of the decorator points to your Model Class.
Inside your function you have **instance** which holds the current instance of the model and the **created** flag which allows you to determine if this is a new record or an old (if the Model is being updated).

Comment: so i guess i can call some specific attributes using **instance.attribute** like it would be **self.attribute**, or there is another way to call them?

Comment: exactly, instance is you model instance, as is self within the model class :)

Answer (score 0):

Signals would be excellent for something like this, but moving the line `super(System, self).save()` to the top of the save method might work as well. That means you first save the instance, before passing the saved object to the LDAP.

Comment: Than you. Actually i tried your suggestion and i must say it works! But i prefere to realize a post_save function working so to divide sections of operations, and also to keep the code cleant.